# How to charge fee on stripe api using c#

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am using Stripe Api to create a customer and then charge it.

What i wanted is to charge my customer whenever it create a sell or charge.
I want 7% of total amount to be credited in my stripe account.

I have tried the Application fee when creating charge with customer Id , but it requires destination to be passed, which requires merchant ID, which always throws error that "No Merchant Found with provided ID".

Comment: Where is the other 93% supposed to go?  To another Stripe account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#creating-payments) say, there are two way to create a charge: `Charging directly` and `Charging through the platform`.
Which of these are you using? (Can I suppose the second since you were talking about the "destination"? ).

They both require connected accounts to do charge, ect.

In the case of [Charging through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), you need that the account is connected to the platform to be visible from the "destination" ([Connecting_Account_Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts)).

If it is not so, explains better the situation in which you find.

---

[application_fee](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge-application_fee):

> A fee in cents that will be applied to the charge and transferred to the application owner's Stripe account. To use an application fee, **the request must be made on behalf of another account**, using the Stripe-Account header, an OAuth key, or the destination parameter. For more information, see the application fees documentation.

[destination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge-destination):

> **An account to make the charge on behalf of**. If specified, the charge will be attributed to the destination account for tax reporting, and the funds from the charge will be transferred to the destination account. The ID of the resulting transfer will be returned in the transfer field of the response. See the documentation for details.